# how to replace some string from outside in json file

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a localization map like:

```
  'en': {
    "timeIsUpTitle": "Time is Up!",

    "workingTimeText": "You are working for{{}} {{}} {{}}.."
  },
  'tr': {
    'timeIsUpTitle': 'Zaman doldu!',

    "workingTimeText": "{}{}{}çalışıyorsun..."
  },
```

how can I fill these {} sections on the outside? I have some getters for these strings such as,

```
  String  workingTimeText(String hours, String minutes, String seconds) => localeValues['workingTimeText']!;

  String get timeIsUpTitle => localeValues['timeIsUpTitle']!;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with format package in pub dev (it's the same as python's format funct.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to update the Map. You can create your own function based on your preferences.

```dart
void main() {
  for (var key in data.keys) {
    Map<String, String>? value = data[key];
    if (value == null) return;
    value.update("workingTimeText", (value) => 'New Data');
  }

  data.values.forEach(print);
}

var data = {
  "en": {
    "timeIsUpTitle": "Time is Up!",
    "workingTimeText": "You are working for{{}} {{}} {{}}.."
  },
  "tr": {
    "timeIsUpTitle": "Zaman doldu!",
    "workingTimeText": "{}{}{}çalışıyorsun..."
  }
};
```

Output:

```
{timeIsUpTitle: Time is Up!, workingTimeText: New Data}
{timeIsUpTitle: Zaman doldu!, workingTimeText: New Data}
```